# How to pass a sorted list (list of dictionaries) to a Django 1.6 template

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-templates

I have a method that needs to display some data that I create from a model in a sorted manner.  I am trying to pass an ordered set to the template.  Here's the method:

```
def club_team_results(request, team_id):
    """Display detailed information for a specific team, including a list of results by event."""
    team = Team.objects.get(pk=team_id)
    team_events_list = EventDivisionTeam.objects.filter(team=team.id).order_by('division__start_date')
    results={}
    # Each match result is listed once, this team can be either of team or opposing_team
    for r in Result.objects.filter(team=team):
        results[r.id] = {'opponent': r.opposing_team.name,
                         'outcome': r.outcome,
                         'scores': r.scores,
                         'phase': r.phase,
                         'match': r.match,
                         'event_division_id': r.division.id,
                        }
    for r in Result.objects.filter(opposing_team=team):
        results[r.id] = {'opponent': r.team.name,
                         'outcome': r.outcome,
                         'scores': r.scores,
                         'phase': r.phase,
                         'match': r.match,
                         'event_division_id': r.division.id,
                         }

    context = {'team_events_list': team_events_list, 'team_results': results, 'team': team, }
    return render(request, 'rank/club_team_results.html', context)
```

I want to pass the results object sorted by the primary key (r.id). I have tried replacing:

```
'team_results': results
```

with

```
'team_results': sorted(results.items())
```

in the context assignment, but no data is passed to the template when I try to sort it. Note that I can't upgrade the Django version at this time (I'll do that this summer), so I'm stuck with 1.6 (currently using Python 3.3 and Django 1.6). Any assistance would be appreciated!

The following is the section of the template that displays the results list:

```
{% for usav_code, result in team_results.items %}
    {% if result.event_division_id == event.division.id %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="alignleft">{{ result.phase }}</td>
            <td class="alignleft">{{ result.match }}</td>
            <td class="alignleft">{{ result.opponent }}</td>
            <td class="alignleft">{{ result.outcome }}</td>
            <td class="alignleft">{{ result.scores }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="5">No results to display.</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If I use the sorted() method on results in the context assignment statement, then the results list in the template hits the empty tag and displays "No results to display."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `sorted(results.items())` is no longer a `dict`, it is a `list` of `tuples` - but you're still trying to call `.items()` on it in the template.

Change:

```
{% for usav_code, result in team_results.items %}
```

to:

```
{% for usav_code, result in team_results %}
```

and it will correctly iterate over the list of tuples.

By default, Django hides any `AttributeError` you get in templates and returns nothing, so the call to the non-existent `.items()` method was resulting in an empty for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean no data is passed to the template with `sorted(results.items())`? If you are ok with getting a list of tuples instead of a dictionary than this should work. Specifically, you might want `sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])` in order to sort by key.

If you want to get a dict in the end, maybe you can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

Then doing `OrderedDict(sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]))` will return a dict that is sorted.

Comment: When using sorted(), including your example that adds key=lambda x:x[0], I hit the {% empty %} tag on the {% for %} iterator for the list.  If I do NOT sorted(), then the list displays correctly, but unsorted.  I'll see if I can add the appropriate section of the template in a code snippet in the original post.

Comment: I just read in the Django 1.10 documentation that 1.10 adds the ability for sorted() to work on "lists of lists".  Could this possibly be related to the issue that I am having?  I am Django 1.6...